# Django2.0，python-version3.6，django-simpl-captcha-5.6，Why is my verification code not appearing?

Tags: django, python-3.x, captcha

I tried to practice a html page for user login.I browse the document and follow the steps to try django-simple-captcha to verify my user login.finally...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSODt.png)

I have already makemigrations, migrate and add captcha to the INSTALL_APPS，and Defined the Form , and Defined view function

```
'views.py'
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import View

from .froms import UserLoginForm
# Create your views here.
class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
    user_login_form = UserLoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'user_login_form':user_login_form})


'forms.py'
 from django import forms
 from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, min_length=5)
    captcha = CaptchaField()

'urls.py'
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='login.html')),
    path('captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
]
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>login</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="#" method="post">
   <p>
    Username:<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Please input you email">
   </p>
   <p>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password">
   </p>
   <p>
    <label>code:</label>
       {{ user_login_form.captcha }}
            </p>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you updated the `urls.py`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question

Comment: OK i have already edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are just rendering the page using `TemplateView` in your urls.py. That's why it does not pass the `user_login_form` to the template context. You should use `LoginView` instead in urls.py.

See  [this example](http://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#validate-the-form)

Comment: I think I will never make this mistake again in my life.thanks